# Parsing a piece of html code as an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string of html

```
var myString = @"<iframe src="http://www.whatever.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>";
XDocument test = XDocument.Parse(myString);
```

that I would like to parse the src value from. My thought was to read the string into an xdocument and then use linq to get at the value.

Is this possible? Is it the right approach?

Comment: Does the parse succeed?

Comment: To parse html, use html parser. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var reader = new XmlTextReader("path/to/myHtmlFile.html");
while (reader.Read())
{
  // Keep reading until we hit an element called iframe
  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "iframe")
  {
    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
    {
      // Keep moving to the next attribute until we hit one called src
      if (reader.Name == "src")
      {
        return reader.Value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will get you the first iframe element's src value. If you have more iframe elements, you might need to make the search a bit smarter.

Answer (score 2):

Use htmlagilitypack, load it as html and call selectsinglemethod with xpath //iframe and on the node use Attributes property with src parameter and take the value property from that.